# How to add redirection exception for logged out users in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I have the code below to redirect my WordPress logged out users to page /login/

```
<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    if ( ! is_page( 'register-member' ) )
     if ( ! is_page( 'groups' ) ){
 wp_redirect( 'https://members.google.com/login/');
 exit;
} 
} ?>
```

And currently i whitelisted /register-member/ and /groups/ so logged out users can access them.

But I'm trying to whitelist more pages and it's not working and I think it's overwritten by the theme (BuddyPress)

Also i'm using "Restrict Content Pro" plugin

So i'm looking for a solution to whitelist other pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these things with `is_user_logged_in()` and `is_front_page()`. If these are not true, then you can use `wp_redirect()` to redirect the user to the home page.

Assuming your forgot password page is a "page," you could use `is_page()` in your logic as well.

You'll need to hook it to action so that it fires late enough to allow checking the page, but early enough to still safely redirect the user (i.e. before headers are sent).  `template_redirect` is ideal for this.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_frontpage_redirect' );
function my_frontpage_redirect() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if ( ! is_front_page() && ! is_page( 'my-password-reset' ) ) {
            wp_redirect( home_url() );
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work.

Also I don't want to redirect them to homepage.

Let's say I want to redirect all logged out users to google.com if they try to access any page, except /register-member/ and /groups/ pages.